# How to set delegate while using GsonJsonObjectReader with MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring-batch multiresource [JsonItemReader](https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/31/spring-batch-4-1-0-m1-released#add-a-new-json-item-reader) to read multiple files from a location as below:

```
public MultiResourceItemReader<Trade> getReader() {
   ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
   Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:" + "D:/files/trade*.json");//trade1.json, trade2.json, etc
   MultiResourceItemReader<Trade> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
   reader.setResources(resources);
   reader.setDelegate(getDelegate());
   return reader;
}

private JsonItemReader<Trade> getDelegate() {
   return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Trade>()
             .jsonObjectReader(new GsonJsonObjectReader<>(Trade.class))
             .resource(??) /* <--- what to specify here since resource is a mandatory field*/
             .name("tradeJsonItemReader")
             .build();
}
```

In the `getDelegate()` is there a way to set a dummy resource given the fact that it is a mandatory field? I am setting resources on the `MultiResourceItemReader` in the `getReader()` method so I shouldn't need to do this.

I cannot simply return a `new GsonJsonObjectReader<>(Trade.class)` from the `getDelegate()` method since the `MultiResourceItemReader` expects a [ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream.html).

Whats my best option here to set the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug, and it seems the same issue would happen with the `StaxEventItemReaderBuilder` as well. The resource should be optional for this use case as it is allowed when using the `FlatFileItemReader` as a delegate of a `MultiResourceItemReader`, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/fb21b30d7d68306b5ab400694502ccd7b2eb8269/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/builder/FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.java#L447-L450).

So I think the same should be done for `JsonItemReaderBuilder` and `StaxEventItemReaderBuilder`. Please open an issue on Github and add a reference to this SO question. Thank you upfront.

Comment: Thanks. Have opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3731

Comment: For future readers until this gets resolved, a hacky way is to just set a dummy string:
.resource(new FileSystemResource("DummyResource)) since this resource would never get used.